# Schema.org in JSON LD format recognized by Google, but shows error in website console

Tags: json

I recently created my own JSON-LD schema and tested it through Googles Structured data testing tool and no errors were detected, but when I checked the website console URL:https://www.policyhouse.com/uae/en

I could see the following error, can someone please help me resolve the issue,

[Facebook Pixel] - Unable to parse JSON-LD tag. Malformed JSON found: '

[image]